# join three tables sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables

```
sales
-----------
date 
order_id

product_details 
-----------
product_id
cost
price

order_detail 
-----------
product_id
order_id
```

I have to minus the sum of cost and price where date is between **__ and __** to show the profit or loss

I have tried this but dont what is the result is showing

```
SELECT ( SUM(p.price) - SUM(p.cost) )
FROM   product_details AS p
       LEFT JOIN order_detail AS o
         ON o.product_id = p.product_id
       JOIN sales AS s
         ON s.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE  s.[date] = ' 15.08.2013'
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and sample output.  It's very difficult to know what the problem is.

Comment: The left join implies you want all product details but the where clause excludes the benefit of the left join.  So do you want all product details regardless if it had a sale or do you want only product details which have had a sale and an order...

Comment: I just want to show the profit which can calculate as price - cost = profit
and from date to date e.g from 20.07.2013 to 20.08.2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming product_id and order_id are unique:

```
SELECT SUM(p.price) - SUM(p.cost) AS Profit
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN order_detail AS o ON s.order_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN product_details AS p ON o.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE s.Date BETWEEN '15.08.2013' AND '16.08.2013'
```

Comment: the answer should be 14000 but I am getting 3201

Comment: Is there a quantity field that we're missing?

Comment: yes I have added and its working thnx
but I am getting 24005 instead of 24000

Comment: I'd have a close look at the data, how are you arriving at that number?  Maybe filter it to a smaller range and try and see how consistent the inconsistency is.

Comment: Its adding +1 to every day
e.g
15.08.2013 = 10000
17.08.2013 = 10000
19.08.2013 = 10000
the result should be 30000 but its 30003

Comment: I cannot possibly fathom why that would occur.  Once again I recommend further sifting through the data.  Unless something is fundamentally different from your code to mine.  Sorry bud. Also please consider upvoting and accepting my answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a `GROUP BY` in your clause, as you're looking for the total profit of each `product id`?

```
SELECT SUM(pd.price) - SUM(pd.cost)
FROM product_details pd
    LEFT JOIN order_details od ON pd.product_id = od.product_id
    INNER JOIN sales s ON od.order_id = s.order_id
-- This is where you'd change your date filter
WHERE s.Date BETWEEN '20.07.2013' AND '20.08.2013'
GROUP BY pd.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct. Just confirm the date range your are using. Or try getting the Dates in a query and then use it accordingly in the where clause.

```
SELECT s.[date],( SUM(p.price) - SUM(p.cost) )
FROM   product_details AS p
LEFT JOIN order_detail AS o
ON o.product_id = p.product_id
JOIN sales AS s
ON s.order_id = o.order_id
group by s.[date]
```

As the Order Id is not unique then please try this:

```
with order_cte(product_id,order_id)as 
(select distinct Product_id, Order_Id from order_detail)

SELECT s.[date],( SUM(p.price) - SUM(p.cost) )
FROM   product_details AS p
LEFT JOIN order_cte AS o
ON o.product_id = p.product_id
JOIN sales AS s
ON s.order_id = o.order_id
group by s.[date]
```

Comment: I am getting result 24005 instead of 24000